Youtube Analytics API: Demographics, Sharing Service and Audience Retention Request Not Returning 'day' Dimension
Why these request is not returning 'day' dimension? I have to come out my logic to scrape the data by video and by country which is taking long time to do the data scraping. Each gcp project have 100k quota per day and I am using 4 gcp project to do this. Scraping the data in parallel for 4 Youtube Channel and there are many videos for the channel and if the video published date is 5 years ago or even earlier, this will causing the scraping process longer. Total I have to scrape 11 Youtube Channel and each channel need to scrape for this 5 table which is 'Sharing Service by Location', 'Sharing Service by Country', 'Video Audience Retention', 'Demographics by Video', and 'Demographics by Country'. I wish to ask why there is no 'day' dimension return for this. I have a client who is interested to getting all the historical data. That's why I should scrape all the historical data. Tired for doing this repeating things.
Expect to scrape the data like others request such as Video Stats, Traffic because these request is returning 'day' dimension.
